# ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundException JSP

Tags: jsp, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am taking 12 records from my database and storing it in a ResultSet since I cannot fetch each element from ResultSet whereever I want. I am using arrayList to store the ResultSet data and then using ArrayList.get() method to retrieve each element.

but the problem is that the data coming from database sometimes can be less than 12 records but I have already accessed arraylist.get(12) so it throws IndexOutOfBoundException. now what I want is to check whether array.get(12)th element is out of bound or not before printing the value of it.

I have tried if(arraylist.get(12)!=null) but it doesn't work probably because again I am trying to access the 12th record which does not exist in the arraylist.

Comment: why u specified size.Is it mandatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list contains 12 items and you want to get the last one, you have to use `.get(11)`, since lists, arrays, sets, etc., are 0-based indexed in JAVA. On the other hand, if you want to get the first one, you have to use `.get(0)` instead of `.get(1)` (which returns the second one).

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to hardcode things like "I want the 12th record of a Collection". If you want to check the size of the collection. You should get the collection size, not trying to access an arbitrary value and see if it works.

Have a look at

http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2009/01/how-to-access-the-size-of-a-collection-in-a-jsp-page-using-jstl-el/

for more details on how to do it.

Comment: @sp00m ... thank you guys for the response i am happy to say that i solved my problem and iam not hardcoding anything since iam using page numbering 12 is the number of records iam showing per page but sometimes what happens is that suppose number of records that is fetched from database is above 12 and below 24 so since you already showing details of 12 records per page ARRAYINDEXOUTOFBOUNDEXCEPTION is thrown..